# Sawtooth wave function

Tags: plotting

I'm trying to plot the sawtooth wave function for -2[Pi]<x <= 4[Pi]. I've used

```
Plot[Sawtooth[x], {x, -2Pi, 4Pi}]
```

but the resulting plot just doesn't seem right. If this method is wrong, how can I got about plotting this sawtooth wave function?

Answer (score 2):

```
Plot[SawtoothWave[x], {x, -2Pi, 4Pi}]
```